# Whenever I install Rivatuner or Ccleaner (along with avast) my Internet stops working

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection

Literally what the title says, and I'm starting to get annoyed about it.

It started a while back ago, my Internet (Ethernet) just stopped working for my pc. I tried everything to get it to work but nothing worked.

I reinstalled my PC, installed everything I needed and just about when I installed MSI Afterburner with Rivatuner the Internet stopped working again. So I thought for myself that either or both Afterburner and Rivatuner was the problem.

I reinstalled my pc again, installed everything again. I tried installing Afterburner without Rivatuner this time and guess what, the Internet worked fine. Until four days ago when the same problem appeared.

I reinstalled my PC once again, but this time I didn't install CCleaner. Because I thought I wouldn't need it.

And Just now, today, when I installed CCleaner (with avast along with CCleaner) to clean my pc a bit, and my Internet stopped working...

I didn't want to reinstall my PC this time because I already had done that four days ago and I was tired of it, so I tried to restart my pc a couple of times but nothing happens.

I uninstall both CCleaner and Avast, restart my PC, and now the Internet works fine while I'm typing this post trying to figure out what the heck is wrong with my PC.

Comment: **Moderator Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Answer (score 0):

First, *how did you use CCleaner*? If you used the default settings for the Windows tab, and did nothing else, that should not affect internet access. If you've checked some options such as *DNS Cache* or *Environment Path*, or use additional `Tools` such as *Duplicate Finder*, it's possible to damage system files. The `Registry` cleaner might remove settings needed by the video card utilities.

Second, CCleaner does *not* need to be installed to work, if that is any part of the issue.

- Uninstall CCleaner completely.
- Open the CCleaner installation file, e.g. `ccsetup554.exe` with an archive utility such as [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html).
- Extract `CCleaner64.exe` and the `Lang` folder to a new folder.
- Move the folder to `C:\Program Files`.
- Create a shortcut to `CCleaner64.exe` for your Start Menu and/or Desktop.

If you do not open it, there should be *no impact at all* on PC operation.

Finally, *Avast!* may be problematic *in your particular setup*. Try a different malware suite, such as the MS Defender that comes with Windows or any of [the many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/avast-home-edition/)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to take a step back.

I would start by installing one of the applications you believe to be proplematic, allow sufficent time to test before moving on to install the next.

Have you tried to give your computer a static IP address?
What networking troubleshooting have you done? As when you say the internet stopped working, are you still able to ping your router?

So many unanswered questions I can think of.

Take your time, try not to let the frustration get the better of you.